# Can't aggregate arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregation

I can create an array of arrays:

```
select array[array[1, 2], array[3, 4]];
     array     
---------------
 {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

But I can't aggregated arrays:

```
select array_agg(array[c1, c2])
from (
    values (1, 2), (3, 4)
) s(c1, c2);
ERROR:  could not find array type for data type integer[]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782268/array-agg-for-array-types

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult(anyarray) (
    SFUNC = array_cat,
    STYPE = anyarray,
    INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

and queries like:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult( ARRAY[[x,x]] ) FROM generate_series(1,10) x;
```

Note that you must aggregate 2-dimensional arrays, so you'll often want to wrap an input array in a single-element `ARRAY[array_to_aggregate]` array constructor.

Comment: Here goes a question of efficiency. Looks like this wil have quadratic complexity.

Comment: @Suor `n(log n)` probably. For better results you'd use an unpacked array as an intermediate state, and a C function.