# psycopg2 returning string rather than decimal array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, python-3.x, numpy, psycopg2

I am querying a database with psycopg2 and python3 to get decimal arrays.

Inside the DB I am concatenating arrays with an aggregate functions like the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947943/cant-aggregate-arrays).

From reading the psycopg2 documentation I was under the impression PostgreSQL decimal arrays should be getting converted to python decimal lists by default, but this is not happening. I am getting a single string instead.

Here is an example return value:

```
{"(\"{1.33,1.37,1.5,1.1,1.576...
```

Do I need to create a custom type-caster as outlined here on the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.new_array_type)? If so, can someone point me in the right direction of how to do it because so far I am getting nowhere.

Alternative suggestions welcome. Ultimately i want these arrays in numpy objects for manipulation and plotting.

EDIT:

Ok, further digging leads me to the conclusion the issue is my aggregate function in the DB. I am using one identical to that shown in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947943/cant-aggregate-arrays).

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_accum(anyarray) (
    SFUNC = array_cat,
    STYPE = anyarray,
    INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

The return from this is coming as a string however.

I am calling it just like in the question linked above:

```
  SELECT array_accum( ARRAY[[x,x]] ) 
   FROM (SELECT subseries FROM series 
    WHERE offset BETWEEN 10 AND 20) x;
```

If I query for an individual subseries I am getting the correct type. After aggregation it is being converted to a string however.

Comment: `>>> cur.execute("select array[[1.2,3.4],[5.6,7.8]] as a")` `>>> r = cur.fetchall()` `>>> print r` `[([[Decimal('1.2'), Decimal('3.4')], [Decimal('5.6'), Decimal('7.8')]],)]` (Python 2.7)

Comment: Post the code you are using

Comment: I have added the problem code above