# Writing a PostgreSQL aggregate function where the input values are arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table whose columns are arrays of reals, like this

```
   my_column
-----------------
{5.7, 1.5, 1.7, ...}
{4.2, 4.1, 2.6, ...}
etc
```

and I wish to yield an aggregate array of sums where each element is the sum of the corresponding elements, down the rows -- something like this

```
   my_column_aggregate
--------------------------------------------------------
{sum(5.7,4.2, etc), sum(1.5,4.1,etc), sum(1.7,2.6,etc) ...}
```

My tables have several such columns and around 10 to 100 unordered rows, with each array having the same count (about 20) of ordered elements. Conceptually, a table is a matrix and of course I could have stored it using some other arrangement but for other reasons it'll probably remain that way.

I need to write a function, `my_agg_sum()`, say, so I can

```
SELECT my_agg_sum (my_column) FROM ... WHERE ...
```

After doing some research, I think I should ultimately install and use **R** http://www.r-project.org/ and  PL/R http://www.joeconway.com/plr/ since I'll probably eventually have more complicated number crunching to do.

In the meantime, however, since my current needs are simple and I'd like to learn some basics of aggregate function writing, I need some help. I thought I could use the built-in function `array_agg()` to amass an array of arrays -- a matrix -- for which I could write my summation function. (Because I'm very new to PL/pgSQL, I'd use this http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.ca/2013/04/introduction-to-postgresql-arrays-basic.html as an example guide.) If I can get an intermediate result

```
{{5.7, 1.5, 1.7, ...}, {4.2, 4.1, 2.6, ...}, etc}
```

I think I'm OK. The problem is, when I try

```
SELECT array_agg (my_column)
```

I get

```
ERROR:  could not find array type for data type real[]
```

It seems arrays of arrays are not directly supported, even though 2D arrays are!

I didn't really understand the responses at http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/could-not-find-array-type-for-data-type-character-varying-td1879264.html

Maybe I need to create a new type

```
CREATE TYPE profile AS (a_name REAL[])
```

and then what?
Or maybe I need to do a load of nested `unnest()`ing or `array_to_string()`ing...?

I could somehow iterate over each array element

```
SELECT  sum (my_column[i])
```

for i, 1 to n, but how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initial array in function to aggregate multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832973/initial-array-in-function-to-aggregate-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: More "prior art" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782268/array-agg-for-array-types) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays).

Comment: Thanks, Erwin. All those examples help my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a pretty simple `CREATE AGGREGATE` statement for this; see [this similar prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15947943/398670).

It's not very efficient, so PL/R will be a much better option. Or writing an aggregate in C if you're brave - the PostgreSQL array API in C is pretty ugly.