# How to use array_agg() for varchar[]

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array, aggregate-functions

I have a column in our database called `min_crew` that has varying character arrays such as `'{CA, FO, FA}'`.

I have a query where I'm trying to get aggregates of these arrays without success:

```
SELECT use.user_sched_id, array_agg(se.sched_entry_id) AS seids
     , array_agg(se.min_crew) 
FROM base.sched_entry se
   LEFT JOIN base.user_sched_entry use ON se.sched_entry_id = use.sched_entry_id
WHERE se.sched_entry_id = ANY(ARRAY[623, 625])
GROUP BY user_sched_id;
```

Both 623 and 625 have the same `use.user_sched_id`, so the result should be the grouping of the seids and the `min_crew`, but I just keep getting this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  could not find array type for data type character varying[]
> ```

If I remove the `array_agg(se.min_crew)` portion of the code, I do get a table returned with the `user_sched_id = 2131` and `seids = '{623, 625}'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [array\_agg for Array Types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782268/array-agg-for-array-types) or [Can't aggregate arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15947943/479863)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard aggregate function [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) only works for base types, not array types as input.
(But **Postgres 9.5+** has a [new variant of `array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) that can!)

You could use the custom aggregate function **`array_agg_mult()`** as defined in this related answer:
[Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762398/selecting-data-into-a-postgres-array-format/11763245#11763245)

Create it once per database. Then your query could work like this:

```
SELECT use.user_sched_id, array_agg(se.sched_entry_id) AS seids
      ,array_agg_mult(ARRAY[se.min_crew]) AS min_crew_arr
FROM   base.sched_entry se
LEFT   JOIN base.user_sched_entry use USING (sched_entry_id)
WHERE  se.sched_entry_id = ANY(ARRAY[623, 625])
GROUP  BY user_sched_id;
```

There is a detailed rationale in the linked answer.

#### Extents have to match

In response to your comment, consider this quote from [the manual on array types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT):

> Multidimensional arrays must have matching extents for each dimension.
>   A mismatch causes an error.

There is no way around that, the array type does not allow such a mismatch in Postgres. You *could* pad your arrays with NULL values so that all dimensions have matching extents.

But I would rather translate the arrays to a comma-separated lists with `array_to_string()` for the purpose of this query and use [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) to aggregate the `text` - preferably with a different separator. Using a newline in my example:

```
SELECT use.user_sched_id, array_agg(se.sched_entry_id) AS seids
      ,string_agg(array_to_string(se.min_crew, ','), E'\n') AS min_crews
FROM   ...
```

#### Normalize

You might want to consider [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema to begin with. Typically, you would implement such an n:m relationship with a separate table like outlined in this example:
[How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: One issue that I'm having is that when the min_crew is not the same for two entries (e.g. {CA, FO, FA} and {CA, FO}, i get the following error: "Detail: Arrays with differing element dimensions are not compatible for concatenation."  It works great when the arrays are the same.  Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: @DarinPeterson: I added another answer to address that.

Comment: I modified the answer to use array_agg() in place of string_agg(), b/c the intent is to maintain separation of the min_crew across seids, so "array_agg(array_to_string(se.min_crew, ',')) AS min_crews" does exactly what is needed.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter is it possible to add the padding NULL value in custom aggrigate function if its a mismatch ?

Comment: @Sarath: Yes, but it gets significantly more expensive. Use a custom function for `SFUNC` in the definition of the aggregate, where you check dimensions with [`array_dims()` or `array_ndims()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) ... That's really a *new question*, not a comment. You can always reference this one for context.

Comment: added as aquestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017890/postgresql-how-to-add-padding-null-in-custom-aggregate-function can you give the syntax