# Pad arrays with NULL to maximum length for custom aggregate function

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

From the answer of the question [How to use array_agg() for varchar[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156168/how-to-use-array-agg-for-varchar),

We can create a custom aggregate function to aggregate n-dimensional arrays in Postgres like:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
   ,STYPE     = anyarray
   ,INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

A constrain is that the values have to share the **same array extents and same length**, handling empty values and different lengths doesn't work.

From the answer:

> There is no way around that, the array type does not allow such a
>   mismatch in Postgres. You could pad your arrays with NULL values so
>   that all dimensions have matching extents.

I have the rows like

```
------ arrayfield

-----  {1},
-----  {},
-----  {abc}

array_agg_mult(ARRAY[arrayfield]) AS customarray
```

I am expecting a aggregate resule like `{{1},NULL,{abc}}`

but it will throw

```
ERROR:  cannot concatenate incompatible arrays
DETAIL:  Arrays with differing element dimensions are not compatible for concatenation.
```

**Is there any way that we can add the padding values in the custom function ?**

I found the issue is when the array *length* is different. `{a},{null},{1}` will aggregate, but `{a,b},{},{1}` will not.

So I need a query where I can add NULL elements to existing arrays.

One solution is to append two NULL always (2 is the max length going to be in that filed) `array_cat(arr, ARRAY[NULL,NULL])` and trim the array to length 2:

```
   {1}   --> {1,NULL,NULL}     --> {1,NULL}
   {NULL}  --> {NULL,NULL,NULL}  --> {NULL,NULL}
   {abc, def}  --> {abc,def,NULL,NULL}  --> {abc, def}
```

But I can't figure out the **syntax**.

Comment: I took the liberty to sharpen your question, assuming that's what you're after.

Comment: Yes , array_dims() or array_ndims() doesn't work for all conditions, can you give the syntax

Comment: Do you need a padding value in the result, or can we just skip violating values? Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the desired result?

Comment: added more description of data and expected values

Comment: You were on the right track with your last idea. `array_fill()` was the missing tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the custom aggregate function `array_agg_mult()` like defined in this related answer:

- [Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762398/selecting-data-into-a-postgres-array-format/11763245#11763245)

Your expected result is impossible:

```
{{1},NULL,{abc}}
```

Would have to  be:

```
{{1},{NULL},{abc}}
```

#### Simple case with 0 or 1 array elements

For the simple case to just replace the empty array:
You can achieve that with:

```
WITH t(arr) AS (
    VALUES
      ('{1}'::text[])
     ,('{}')
     ,('{abc}')
   )
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[CASE WHEN arr = '{}' THEN '{NULL}' ELSE arr END])
FROM   t;
```

#### Dynamic padding for n elements

Using `array_fill()` to pad arrays with NULL elements up to the maximum length:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[
         arr || array_fill(NULL::text
                         , ARRAY[max_elem - COALESCE(array_length(arr, 1), 0)])
       ]) AS result
FROM   t, (SELECT max(array_length(arr, 1)) AS max_elem FROM t) t1;
```

Still only works for **1-dimensional** basic arrays.

#### Explain

- Subquery `t1` computes the maximum length of the basic 1-dimensional array.
- `COALESCE(array_length(arr, 1), 0)` computes the length of the array in this row.
  `COALESCE` defaults to `0` for `NULL`.
- Generate padding array for the difference in length with `array_fill()`.
- Append that to `arr` with `||`
- Aggregate like above with `array_agg_mult()`.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c7cbf/5) demonstrating **all**.
<sub>Output in SQL Fiddle is misleading, so I cast result to text there.</sub>

Comment: Ok, but why there is the same issue when i changed last data to `{abc,efg}` ?

Comment: @Sarath: dimensions have to match. In that case you'd have to pad all basic arrays with NULL elements up to the `max(array_length(arr, 1))`, so `{1}` becomes `{1, NULL}`, etc.

Comment: Ok, but even if the condition null wont work in case, like
`array_agg_mult(ARRAY[CASE WHEN array_length(arr,1) = 0 THEN '{NULL,NULL}' ELSE arr END])`

Comment: @Sarath: No, it's a bit more complex than that. Added another solution above.