# Pad arrays with NULL to maximum length for custom aggregate function - no array_fill function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-8.2

This is almost same question as [Pad arrays with NULL to maximum length for custom aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017890/pad-arrays-with-null-to-maximum-length-for-custom-aggregate-function). the only problem with the answer provided is that function array_fill doesn't exist in Postgres 8.2.

How can I make it useable given the version I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t AS (SELECT arr::text[] FROM UNNEST('{"{1}","{}","{a,b,c}"}'::text[]) arr);
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(arr || nulls[1:max-(1+array_upper(arr, 1)-array_lower(arr, 1))], '{}'), nulls[1:max])
FROM t,
  (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT NULL::text FROM generate_series(1, 100)) AS nulls) a,
  (SELECT 1 + max(array_upper(arr, 1)-array_lower(arr, 1)) AS max FROM t) m
```

Comment: the array I tried to pad with null is an integer array. Do I have to convert it to text array? got ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] || text[]
LINE 2: COALESCE(NULLIF(arr || nulls[1:6-(1+array...
                                               ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @fairybetty just change the `::text[]` and `::text` to int :)

Answer (score 1):

```
do $$
declare
  arr int[] := array[1,2,3];
begin
  raise info '%', arr;
  arr[1] := coalesce(arr[1]); -- Set lower bound if array is null
  arr[10] := coalesce(arr[10]); -- Set upper bound
  raise info '%', arr;
end $$;
```

Output:

```
INFO:  {1,2,3}
INFO:  {1,2,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
```

Not a complete answer, but it is easy to convert it to the function.

Disclaimer: Tested on PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: thanks Abelisto. My version is 8.2... so this doesn't work.