# PostgreSQL: Undefined function array_agg(enumlabel)

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, yii2

I am newbie in PostgreSQL.
When I apply migrations on the hosting I see an error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7
> ERROR: function array_agg(name) does not exist
> LINE 12: array_to_string((select array_agg(enumlabel) from pg_enum...
> ```

My hosting has PostgreSQL 8.3.11.

The SQL being executed:

```
SELECT
    d.nspname AS table_schema,
    c.relname AS table_name,
    a.attname AS column_name,
    t.typname AS data_type,
    a.attlen AS character_maximum_length,
    pg_catalog.col_description(c.oid, a.attnum) AS column_comment,
    a.atttypmod AS modifier,
    a.attnotnull = false AS is_nullable,
CAST(pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) AS varchar) AS column_default,
coalesce(pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) ~ 'nextval',false) AS is_autoinc,

array_to_string((select array_agg(enumlabel)
from pg_enum
where enumtypid=a.atttypid)::varchar[],',') as enum_values,

CASE atttypid
    WHEN 21 /*int2*/ THEN 16
    WHEN 23 /*int4*/ THEN 32
    WHEN 20 /*int8*/ THEN 64
    WHEN 1700 /*numeric*/ THEN
CASE WHEN atttypmod = -1
THEN null
ELSE ((atttypmod - 4) >> 16) & 65535
END
    WHEN 700 /*float4*/ THEN 24 /*FLT_MANT_DIG*/
    WHEN 701 /*float8*/ THEN 53 /*DBL_MANT_DIG*/
ELSE null
END AS numeric_precision,
CASE
    WHEN atttypid IN (21, 23, 20) THEN 0
    WHEN atttypid IN (1700) THEN
CASE
    WHEN atttypmod = -1 THEN null
ELSE (atttypmod - 4) & 65535
END
ELSE null
END AS numeric_scale,
CAST(information_schema._pg_char_max_length(information_schema._pg_truetypid(a, t),
information_schema._pg_truetypmod(a, t)) AS numeric) AS size,
a.attnum = any (ct.conkey) as is_pkey
FROM
pg_class c
    LEFT JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef ad ON a.attrelid = ad.adrelid AND a.attnum = ad.adnum
    LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace d ON d.oid = c.relnamespace
    LEFT join pg_constraint ct on ct.conrelid=c.oid and ct.contype='p'
WHERE
    a.attnum > 0 and t.typname != ''
    and c.relname = 'migration'
    and d.nspname = 'public'
ORDER BY
    a.attnum;
```

in `.../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:628`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20156444/3599237

Comment: Before you do anything else, consider the [versioning page of Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Postgres 8.3 has reached EOL in 2013 and is unsupported and just too old for any serious work. Upgrade to a current version.

Answer (score 6):

[Like commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269612/postgresql-undefined-function-array-aggenumlabel#comment54341104_33269612), your best option is to update to a current version of Postgres. There is no `array_agg()` function in Postgres 8.3.

**However**, you can substitute with a basic [**`ARRAY` constructor**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS), which has been there since at least Postgres 7.4 and happens to be **more efficient for this anyway**, even in current Postgres. Replace the bolded part of the query in your question with:

```sql
array_to_string(ARRAY(
   SELECT enumlabel FROM pg_enum
   WHERE  enumtypid = a.atttypid)::text[], ',') AS enum_values,
```

In Postgres 9.0 or later you can simplify with [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html):

```sql
(SELECT string_agg(enumlabel, ',') FROM pg_enum
 WHERE  enumtypid = a.atttypid) AS enum_values,
```

The simple ARRAY constructor should still be faster, though.
BTW, `pg_enum` itself was introduced with Postgres 8.3 (for `enum` types).

Answer (score 2):

There is no `array_agg` function in PostgreSQL 8.3. See the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-8-4.html).

Answer (score 2):

There's no `array_agg` in Postgresql 8.3.

**But if you just cant't upgrade, you can then just create `array_agg` function as easy as this:**

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg (
    sfunc = array_append,
    basetype = anyelement,
    stype = anyarray,
    initcond = '{}'
);
```

---

**NOT DIRECTLY RELATED TO THE QUESTION:**

If you choose to upgrade from 8.x to 9.x version, some (bad written) queries will not work any more... specially those with implicit casts:

```
select * from my_table where my_int_column = some_text_value
```

So, you have to rewrite them adding explicit cast:

```
select * from my_table where my_int_column = some_text_value::int
```

or you can create some "autocasts" in way of keep them working while you rewrite them down:

```
CREATE CAST (varchar AS integer) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
CREATE CAST (character AS integer) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```