# Generate 2d array with given values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to turn a 1d jsonb array

```
[1, 2]
```

into 2d array where its elements are repeated 3 times (the result can be in jsonb)

```
[[1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2]]
```

My attempt doesn't work

```
select array(select array_fill(a::text::integer, array[3])) 
  from jsonb_array_elements('[1,2]'::jsonb) as a;

ERROR:  could not find array type for data type integer[]
```

Maybe it would work in later PG version, but I'm restricted to PG 9.4.8

What are the other ways?

Comment: it does work in 9.6 if you use `array_agg()` instead of `array()`

Comment: other ways?  perhaps write a plpgsql function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to replace `array()` with `array_agg()`, then you'll have what you expect, starting with Postgres 9.5.

That being said, your issue is with `array_agg()` not being able to aggregates arrays prior to 9.5.

Then are multiple [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832973/initial-array-in-function-to-aggregate-multi-dimensional-array) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782268/array-agg-for-array-types) for you, but basically you'll need to create a new aggregate function `array_agg_mul`:

```sql
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat,
    STYPE     = anyarray,
    INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

then running the following query should work:

```
SELECT
    array_agg_mult(array[array_fill(a::text::integer, array[3])])
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[1,2]'::jsonb) as a;
```

Then you should get:

```
  array_agg_mult
-------------------
 {{1,1,1},{2,2,2}}
```